# How can I tell logstash to read file over ssh

Tags: input, logstash, acquia

Using the ELK stack, I have to parse some file but they are remote.
My solution

- rsync over ssh to get the remote file locally

My concern is that my elasticsearch index is growing exponentially (more tha 130MB) whereas the logfile are only 25MB.
Is that possible that each rsync cron (*/5 mn) leads logstash to read the whole file again without taking the *sincedb* stuff ?

Thanks for your help :)

The context, I'm using acquia as hoster for drupal site and so I do not have control over how I can access the logfile

Guillaume Renard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wanted to check acquia's log, I try another way, use of logstream (https://github.com/acquia/logstream) and supervisord (http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) and it saves my day.

```
...
[program:logstream_artecinema_drupal-watchdog]
command=logstream tail prod:artetv prod --no-color --types=drupal-watchdog
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/logstream/artecinema_drupal-watchdog.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=20MB
stdout_logfile_backups=7
environment=HOME="/root"
...
```

And my logstash read the logfile

```
file {
    path => "/var/log/logstream/artecinema_drupal-watchdog.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "drupal-watchdog"
    add_field => { "platform" => "cinema" }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Logstash keeps track of files by inode number and by the position (offset) inside the file.  Run the rsync once, check the inode, run it again, and check again.

```
ls -i logfile.txt
```

If they have the same inode number, logstash should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add option to rsync command:

```
--append
```

It adds new lines to the end. It also implies `--inplace` which preserves inode.